# What does thread "Thread 2" do in JavaFX application?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

When I create a simple non-multithreading JavaFX application and start it, the application creates some threads (JavaFX Application Thread, JavaFX-Launcher and others). Most of these threads are named but in all my JavaFX application there is one unnamed thread ("Thread-1" or "Thread-2"). I definitely don't create my own threads because I tried to start Hello World JavaFX application (generated by IDEA) and there is "Thread-2" in it too.
What does this thread do? Why is it unnamed?

P.S. I use VisualVM to see threads in a process.

Comment: Just wondering: why do you care?

Comment: I'm a student and it is a question from my lecturer )

Comment: So why does (s)he care?

Comment: I think you should not let us tell you what it might be. Use VisualVM and do some CPU profiling. It should tell you which Classes and methods are used there.

Comment: The question can only be usefully answered in the context of the objective of why it is asked. Maybe the objective is for you to learn how to use VisualVM to profile threads. Maybe the objective is for you to understand something about multithreading. Or maybe it is for you to understand something about the implementation of the JavaFX platform. Since you don't even understand what the objective is, there is certainly no-one here who does. You should be asking your lecturer this question, not posting it on a forum.

Comment: The question is about implementation of JavaFX platform. I think it's strange enough that each JavaFX application has unnamed thread.

Comment: The reason people are asking "why do you care?" is because it's an implementation detail.  If you use some other JVM and some other implementation of JavaFX and the standard libraries, then there might not even _be_ a "Thread 2".

Comment: Re, "I think it's strange enough..."  Doesn't seem strange to me.  I seldom give threads explicit names.  If it's a thread that is not described in the public API documentation (i.e., a thread that will never run client code) then naming it might _not_ be a smart idea.  Sometimes, if you give curious developers more visibility into should-have-been-private details of a library or a tool, you end up answering more support phone calls and support e-mails.  Give them less insight into your implementation, and maybe they'll get desperate enough to RTFM.

Comment: Hm, OK, I understood that there is no reason for me to know what that thread really does. Thank you

Comment: If you really need to know, propably it's best to use `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` to get the stacktraces and log the relevant stacktraces (or use some other way to access that information)... This should give you an idea of the classes/methods they're working with....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all the commentators. They persuaded me that existing such threads as "Thread-1" or "Thread-2" depends on JavaFX and JVM implementations, and there is no reason for me to know why such threads exist.